# Flutter: Use NumberFormat.compact() And Limiting Decimal Places

Tags: flutter, dart

Is there a way to use both `NumberFormat.compact()` in addition to limiting the number of decimal places in the output with something like `NumberFormat('.#')`. I did not see how to do that properly.

```
final unitCompact = NumberFormat.compact().format(value);
```

Currently, `unitCompact` will be `1.23K`. I want it to be `1.2K`.

Comment: Do you mean that you want `1.2K`?

Comment: @jamesdlin yes sorry, that was a typo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```dart
final formatter = NumberFormat.compact();
formatter.maximumFractionDigits = 1;
formatter.significantDigitsInUse = false;
final unitCompact = formatter.format(value);

// Check the results
print(unitCompact);
```

Comment: That worked for the values over 1,000! However, now it is showing a decimal for values under 1,000. Turning `484` into `484.2`, which takes up too much space in my app. Any suggestion on how to prevent that in your flow?

Comment: I guess a simple validation, like if your number >= 1000, use that formatter, otherwise just show the original value.

Comment: btw I tried the code using `formatter.format(484)` and the result is 484, I don't see that extra decimal, u sure your value is int?

Comment: It was a `double` but converting it to `Int()` first and then running the formatter worked. Thank you!